# How to set a div's height equal to that div's width?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to set the height of each of the div's under to equal that div's width.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row box-row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 box-container"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 box-container"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 box-container"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 box-container"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried with `$('.box-container').css('height', $('.box-container').width());`, but that sets all the div's height to equal the first divs width.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the function parameter of jQuery `height()` method:

```
$('.box-container').height(function(){
    return $(this).width();
});
```

Comment: With this approach, the page becomes sluggish (and the divs begin to flicker when I resize the window (I have a relatively fast PC)). I was hoping to get this done with the .css attribute as this seems to be smoother on the system...?

Comment: @allegutta This is not relevant to `height()` vs `css()` method but sounds like just issue regarding responsive design using CSS rules as media queries. Now i guess your best bet is to use instead a CSS only approach, e.g: http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html  But you'd have better to provide a minimalistic sample in question itself replicating your issue

Comment: Yes, you are right. Tried with the use of the .css attribute, and it didn't make the flickering any better (my assumptions were wrong).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.each` since it is a list of items with different widths:

```
$('.box-container').each(function(){
       $(this).css('height', $(this).width() + 'px');
});
```

Comment: Hmmm, it does not work...

Comment: can you see the update `+ 'px'`

Comment: Yes, that worked, thanks. But the other answer is cleaner, and I will accept that. Thanks for bringing a solution to the table though! :)